# Uso de condições em matrizes

Tags: c, c++, array

Preciso fazer um programa que leia uma matriz 4X4  e que posteriormente faça a soma dos valores em cada linha e depois por cada coluna. Não sei ao certo como definir minha condição.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int valores[4][4];
int i,j, somacol, somalin;

for(i=0; i<4; i++){
      for(j=0; j<4; j++){
printf("Informe os valores:", i+1, j+1);
scanf("%d", &valores[i][j]);
}
}
for(i=0; i<4; i++){                     
     for(j=0; j<4; j++){
printf("%d\t", valores[i][j]);
}
printf("\n");
}
for(i=0; i<4; i++){
     for(j=0; j<4; j++){
 somalin=valores[i][j];
 }
 }
 for(i=0; i<4; i++){
 for(j=0; j<4; j++){
 somacol=valores[i][j];
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int valores[4][4];
    int i, j, soma;
    
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            printf("Informe os valores de [%d, %d]:\n", i + 1, j + 1);
            scanf("%d", &valores[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {                     
        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            printf("%d\t", valores[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        soma = 0;
        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            soma += valores[i][j];
        }
        printf("Soma da linha %d: %d\n", i + 1, soma);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        soma = 0;
        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            soma += valores[j][i];
        }
        printf("Soma da coluna %d: %d\n", i + 1, soma);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/Zu5Y1Y). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/didanbzb-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/Sum.c).

Não tem erro algum na condição.

Dei uma organizada no código porque isto ajuda entender o que está acontecendo.

A lógica toda da soma estava incorreta. Não reiniciava a variável de soma (que pode ser a mesma) em cada mudança de linha/coluna. E não estava imprimindo quando terminada cada soma.

Não estava somando de fato, e sim estava substituindo o valor em cada passada.

Note que no primeiro laço eu usei `[i][j]` porque precisa pegar cada linha e depois cada coluna dela. No segundo eu usei `[j][i]` porque preciso pegar cada coluna e depois cada linha dela.

Answer (score 5):

Na verdade você precisa de quatro `somalin` e quatro `somacol`, um para cada linha/coluna em `valores`.

Sendo assim, depois de popular a matriz, você vai fazer um `for` duplo para endereçar cada elemento e incrementar a soma da linha e da coluna respectivas.

Passo a passo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    int valores[4][4];
    int i, j, somacol[4], somalin[4];
```

Primeiro obtemos os valores.  Aqui você faz isto com `printf()`e `scanf()`, mas pode convir de você isolar esta funcionalidade numa função para caso depois você queira obter estes valores de um arquivo ou coisa do gênero.

```
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i ++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j ++) {
```

Na hora de chamar o `printf()` e amigos, lembre-se de colocar o especificador de formato (`%d` neste caso); senão não vai aparecer nenhum dos valores dinâmicos que você quer mostrar.

```
            printf("Informe os valores (%d, %d): ", i + 1, j + 1);
```

Quanto ao `scanf()` e afins, lembre-se de sempre começar a *string* de formato com um espaço em branco para que ele "coma" o retorno de carro que você deu na vez anterior que chamou `scanf()`.  Além disso, como a matriz é de `int`, tem que passar o endereço do elemento matricial (com o operador `&`):

```
            scanf(" %d", &(valores[i][j]));
        }
    }
```

Depois, inicializamos todos os `somalin` e `somacol` para zero para podermos usá-los com o operador de incremento `+=`.

```
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i ++) {
        somalin[i] = somacol[i] = 0;
    }
```

Agora vem a parte que interessa: Fazemos um `for` duplo de forma que, no corpo do segundo `for`, temos os índices de um dos dezesseis elementos de `valores`. Basta aqui incrementar a soma da linha e da coluna correspondentes àquele elemento:

```
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i ++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j ++) {
            somalin[i] += valores[i][j];
            somacol[j] += valores[i][j];
        }
    }
```

Depois disso, basta fazer qualquer coisa com os valores e retornar.  Se você estiver fazendo isto na `main()`, lembre-se que ela retorna `int` e dê um `return 0;` antes de sair.  São bons modos.

```
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i ++) {
        printf("Soma da %dª linha: %d\tSoma da %dª coluna: %d\n", i + 1, somalin[i], i + 1, somacol[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```